# Pausing issue while looping a music for x number of times

Tags: android, loops, media-player

Everything works perfectly, only problem is pausing. I wanted to repeat some long media for 5 times and also I wanted to pause the media in-between whenever I need.

But when I press pause/play button the `playsound();` method is called again and again so the music plays more than 5 time.

This is my code

```
ImageButton bv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {
                bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                playsound();
            }
        }
    });
public void playsound() {
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
          int count = 1; 
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count < 5) {
                  count++;
                  mp.start();   
                  mp.seekTo(0);
                }
        }
    });  mp.start();
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Declare `int count = 1;`  globally.

Comment: i just wanted to change the value of count = 1 every time when OnCompletionListener(); is called. so i cant declare it globally.